# How to declare the type in flow of a react redux component with defaultProps?

Tags: javascript, react-redux, flowtype, flow-typed

Example1 below with type interference works but my attempts to declare the export to improve type checking fails (see Example2 and Example3).

```
// @flow

import * as React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

// flow errors below will be the same if Props is an exact type {|...|}
type Props = {
    prop1: number,
    prop2: number,
}

class ExampleClass extends React.Component<Props> {
    static defaultProps = { prop2: 1 }

    render() {
        return this.props.prop1 + this.props.prop2
    }
}

// works, but what is the type of Example1?
export const Example1 = connect(null, null)(ExampleClass)

// Cannot assign connect(...)(...) to Example2 because undefined [1] is incompatible with number [1] in property prop2 of type argument P [2].
export const Example2: React.ComponentType<Props> = connect(null, null)(ExampleClass)
export const example2 = <Example2 prop1={1} />

// Cannot assign connect(...)(...) to Example3 because
// property prop1 is read-only in Props [1] but writable in object type [2] in type argument P [3].
// property prop2 is read-only in Props [1] but writable in object type [2] in type argument P [3].
export const Example3: React.ComponentType<React.ElementConfig<React.ComponentType<Props>>> = connect(null, null)(ExampleClass)
export const example3 = <Example3 prop1={1} />

// Note that this works but I'm looking for a way to declare 
// the type without repeating the list of properties
export const Example2a: React.ComponentType<{prop1: number, prop2?: number}> = connect(null, null)(ExampleClass)
```

Reference the code here https://github.com/jacobwallstrom/FlowTypeExampleIssue

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment but I'm not able to yet. Anyways, it looks like your example repo is using an older version of Flow. As of version 0.89.0, [Flow's support for higher order components](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/fa3022cbd5dc0bd23a2186107798566617d6c842/website/en/docs/react/hoc.md) (HOCs) has increased tremendously. If you are still facing this issue, or something similar, I would recommend that you upgrade to 0.89.0, use [react-redux's flow typings](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/react-redux_v5.x.x/flow_v0.89.x-/react-redux_v5.x.x.js), and investigate again.